# How to include question mark (?) in text using twitter share button on asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I am using twitter share button on my site.

This is my code:

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<%# Eval("Title") %>"></a>
```

As you can see, the text is `<%# Eval("Title") %>` with question mark text.

So, text is 'How old are you?'

But if I clicked the button, it only shows 'How old are you' (without the question mark).

[image: twitter-share]

How do I include the question mark on the text?

Thank You.

Comment: "... you can’t ask a question on Twitter today if you’re using Twitter.com to access the platform. At least, you can’t until this bug is fixed." http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/twitter-question-mark-bug/467337

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `%3F` where the ? should be.

Hope this helps!